# GKE load balancing + ingress controlller for dev env

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress

I've got some domain `example.com` with some subdomains (`foo.example.com`, `bar.example.com`, etc). That's hosted in GKE and contains one ingress with the mass of routing. This all used to be deployed manually.

Now I've created subdomain `dev.example.com` for my stage infrastructure instance. It should be something like `foo.dev.example.com`, `bar.dev.example.com`, etc.

I want to deploy everything via helm. I've got a standard chart structure for my services (like `deployment/stateful set` + `ClusterIP service` + `ingress`). So I need a load balancer that would send all requests with host `*.dev.example.com` to GKE ingress controller avoiding using external static IP address per ingress. Is it possible? Or I could I bind all my ingresses to one static IP address?

Answer (score 0):

GKE default ingress ([GCE ingress class](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce)) will automatically spin up and setup an [HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/) that has [path-based routing capabilities](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#url_maps).

You can also use [other ingress controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) that will create [Network load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/) resources and will automatically bind to an external address.

Currently, is not possible to attach all the external load balancer addresses to a single one in GCP.

However, you can use [GCE ingress's features](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#remarks) to handle [multiple hosts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting). In this case, `*.example.com` and `*.dev.example.com`, can be pointed to a different set of services and deployments within the cluster using the same ingress (and hence, the same public address).